# STM32F205 SPI RXNE flag is not set

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm using STM32F205's SPI1 in master mode. And the RXNE flag is never set during transactions. Here's a part of SPI initialization:

```
SPI1->CR1 = SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SPE;
SPI1->CR2 = 0;
```

Then I'm trying to perform transmition/receiving of a single byte:

```
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_FLAG_TXE)) {}  // wait for compeltion of the previous Tx
SPI1->DR = 0xAB;                      // transmit some byte

while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_FLAG_RXNE)) {}  // wait for byte to be received
uint8_t result = SPI1->DR;
```

This code stucks at the waiting for RXNE flag. I tried to wait for busy flag `BSY = 0` instead of `RXNE = 1` and SPI began to work. It seems RXNE is never set.

Comment: Spupid question first - did you enable SPI1 clocking in apropriate RCC register? Another one - what is `SPI_FLAG_TXE` and why don't you use `SPI_SR_TXE` from the standard header?

Comment: 1. Yes, I have enabled clocks. SPI transmits data and is able to receive data if I check flag BSY=0. But I've never seen RXNE flag is set.
2. It's the same. I took it from STM's headers `#define SPI_FLAG_TXE   SPI_SR_TXE`

Answer (score 10):

I quess Your's SPI communication is 8-bit? (uint8_t result = SPI1->DR). On STM32F051 I have the same problem RXNE flag was not set after recieving 1 byte. The problem is that STM triggers this flag after 16-bit by default. 
In STM32F0 I found solution (it propably will be the same in F2):

The RXNE flag is set depending on the FRXTH bit value in the SPIx_CR2 register:  If FRXTH is set, RXNE goes high and stays high until the RXFIFO level is greater or equal to 1/4 (8-bit). If FRXTH is cleared (default), RXNE goes high and stays high until the RXFIFO level is greater than or equal to 1/2 (16-bit).

So set this bit you can do it using API instruction: 
SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(SPIx, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);

Hope it helps, 
Best wishes from Poland

Answer (score 2):

suggestion only:

```
SPI1->CR1 = SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SPE;
SPI1->CR2 = 0;
```

you are enablling SPI before writing to CR2 register. reverse the above OR enable SPI only after writing to CR2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `STM32L072CZ`.
My solution was to enable the `SPI_CR2_SSOE` bit.
Still I am not using the SPI1 slave select pin for selecting slave, I am using a  software GPIO pin for that.

```
SPI1->CR1 = SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_BR | SPI_CR1_SSM;
SPI1->CR2 = SPI_CR2_SSOE |SPI_CR2_RXNEIE;
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
```